# How to get WP posts between today and expiration date?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi guys/girls help needed, please,

i have wordpress site about events and need to pull 10, 20 posts and sort that by expiration date which is custom field.

expiration date is in format '31/12/2012' (d/m/y) i need to take posts between today and that expiration date and sort it by that expiration date so the posts that expire sooner are on top.

Please, if somebody can help, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

My English is not good enough, to help you with PHP code.
but you can Download Plugin called Post Expirator from WordPress's site or click these links. 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-expirator/

If you needs any more information about how to set up, let me know.

Comment: Hi, i saw that plugin, problem is my site is already established, need some query that works with this date format, thanks!